# Отложенная инициализация параметров конструктора суперкласса (Java)

Tags: java, наследование, конструктор, инициализация

Сложилась ситуация, когда нужно инициализировать переменную, передаваемую в параметр конструктора **суперкласса** в классе-наследнике **во время выполнения программы.**
*Для наглядности:*

```
public class Enemy extends Country{ 
  private int damage;
  private final String[] arr = new String[]{"first", "second"};

  public Enemy() {
    super(arr[0]); //Проблема с полем arr
    //cannot reference arr before supertype constructor has been called
  }
}
```

Как я могу решить данную проблему в рамках текущего класса...
Заранее спасибо за любую информацию)

### Для решения ошибки необходимо сделать ваше поле статичным (*static*).

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963775/cannot-reference-x-before-supertype-constructor-has-been-called-where-x-is-a)

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь)